# Why does NAT64 require DNS rewriting?

Tags: ipv6, nat

When a IPv6 only host wants to reach a IPv4 only host, why does the DNS server (or possibly the NAT-PT gateway?) have to rewrite the A responses to AAAA?

Couldn't IPv6 simply embed the IPv4 address in the destination field of an IPv6 packet (e.g. by simply prefixing it with zeroes or some other, well-known prefix), and leave it to the default gateway to do all the translation?

I don't quite understand the motivation for DNS64.

Comment: Duplicated in [this ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/355197/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Couldn't IPv6 simply embed the IPv4 address in the destination field
>   of an IPv6 packet (e.g. by simply prefixing it with zeroes or some
>   other, well-known prefix), and leave it to the default gateway to do
>   all the translation?

This is exactly what happens. The DNS server takes the IPv4 address (A record), prefixes it with a prefix (there is a well-known prefix 64:FF9B::/96, but it can be any site-specific prefix). Because the DNS64 resolver does it in one place all the hosts don't have to know about it: they just get an IPv6 address that they can connect to. If all the hosts know how to do the prefixing then you wouldn't need the DNS64 server, but changing all the hosts can be difficult. Therefore the DNS64 part is invented to do it automatically in one place.

Comment: Ok, so I guess there is a pretty good reason why it is being used, but just out of curiosity: Why is there no well-known prefix? Hosts could automatically select it in case there is no IPv4 route to the target host, and all the DNS hassle could be avoided. (Hardwired IP addresses would still work, too.) Or would that interfere with the sockets API (after all, a requested IPv4 connection would suddenly be an IPv6 one)?

Comment: The well known prefix is 2002::/16

Comment: But that's 6to4, right? There would be no way for the hosts in the network to have "native", routable IPv6 addresses.

Comment: 2002::/16 is *not* for DNS64/NAT64, that is 6to4. The well-known-prefix is 64:FF9B::/96, and the reason for DNS64 is that changing one DNS server is easier than changing all hosts, especially in a large network.

Comment: So that scenario was not considered when IPv6 was designed (or considered not to be relevant to the core standard), and DNS64 is the hack that makes it work? Or am I missing something? Would defaulting to that prefix in case no IPv4 interface is available by all IPv6 hosts break anything?

Comment: The migration plan was: make the two protocols independent so that they can safely be deployed side-by-side while we still have enough IPv4 addresses to do this. IPv6 has a higher priority than IPv4 to make sure that IPv6 is used when possible. Then, when all (well, most) systems have both we can remove IPv4. What happened is that most organizations thought: 'as long as we have IPv4 we don't need IPv6' and so they didn't deploy it. You are right: DNS64/NAT64 was not supposed to be needed. Migration never happened because everybody kept procrastinating, and now we have a big problem.